# rspec, unknown attribute question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I am working through the (excellent) railstutorial.org site have have a basic question about rspec.

When I run the below test on a new user model, I get an "unknown attribute: username" message and a failed test.

```
  before(:each) do
   @attr = { :lname_e => "User", :fname_e => "Test", :email => "user@example.com", :username => "testUser" }
  end

  it "should create a new instance given valid attributes" do
    User.create!(@attr)
  end
```

Error syntax is

```
Failures:
  1) User should create a new instance given valid attributes
     Failure/Error: User.create!(@attr)
     unknown attribute: username
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The field is in the users table (string), it's in the model as attr_accessible and in the console I can create a user with exactly the same syntax in the test. This "username" field was added via a migration after creating the initial table, is there some other file I need to update here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Did you run `rake db:test:prepare`?

Answer (score 22):

The field may be missing from your test database, but present in your development database (which is why the console is working).

Try making sure your migrations are all up to date and then update the test database:

```
rake db:migrate
rake db:test:prepare
```