# Rspec - unknown attribute error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I followed the Restauranlty tutorial at rubyonrailstutor.com and everything worked perfectly. Now I'm trying to implement the same tests in my project, which has more models with associations between them and I'm getting errors.

I've tried researching this problem, and even came across a few questions on this site - most notably [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27815020/rspec-cant-write-unknown-attribute-enum) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817510/rspec-unknown-attribute-question).

I have the following models:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist

  validates_presence_of :title
  validates_presence_of :no_of_tracks

end

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :albums
end
```

And I have the following factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :artist do
    name "MyString"
    image "MyString"
    bio "MyString"
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :album do
    title "MyString"
    no_of_tracks 0
    artist
  end
end
```

Apart from following the Restaurantly tutorial, this is my first time testing so I also looked at [this guide](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations) for setting up factory girl for models with associations.

My test is:

```
describe Album do
  subject(:album) { FactoryGirl.build :album, title: nil, artist: nil,
    no_of_tracks: nil }
  it { expect(album.valid?).to be_false }
end
```

But when I run it it fails with the error: `can't write unknown attribute artist_id`.

The questions I mentioned above suggested that perhaps my database has not been properly migrated but I've run both

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

and

```
bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
```

to no avail. As I said, I'm very, very new to testing so if anyone could point me in the right direction I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks fine.
Do you really have a column `artist_id` in your `albums` table ?

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple! I'd named my column artist by mistake instead of artist_id. Changed it and it all works fine now.  Thank you! I'll accept you answer as soon as SO let me :0

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `albums` table in your database does not have `artist_id` foregin key.